# can't get value from spring, web-flow

Tags: jsp, spring-webflow

I'm a newbie in spring framework and web-flow, 
I'm trying to get the value of a textarea, but still couldn't get it.
in my someFlow.xml file I declared my variable with 
`<var name="varName" class="java.lang.String"/>`

in my xhtml page the textarea is defined as follows:
`<injsf:inputtextarea id="richText_varName" label="#{lbl.textarea}" rows="1" size="50" required="true" value="#{varName}"/>`

when I type 

 `<evaluate expression="someClass.someMethod(varName)"/>`

the variable varName is blank, but when I type

 `<evaluate expression="someClass.someMethod('some Text')"/>`
I can get the text.

what sould be the problem?

why I cant get the value from the textarea

Comment: <injsf:inputtextarea> is a textarea component, which works well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you Bozho, your comment let me think different :)

from the `<injsf:textarea>` component I was supposed to get the value with `entityValue`, not just `value`

```
<injsf:inputtextarea id="richText_aciklama" label="#{lbl.label.gnl.aciklama}" rows="1" size="50" required="true" entityValue="#{fh.aciklama}"/>
```